# Angular detect when a request is sent and finish in Angular 6

Tags: angular, request, components, angular6

I would like to know how could do something like this in a nicer way:

```js
const isLoading: Boolean = true;

this.sendRequest(resource).subscribe(attachmentwithdata => {
  isLoading = false;
  saveAs(attachmentwithdata.data, attachmentwithdata.name);
});
```

"My way" is pretty ugly and I would like to know how readers normally do it. To be more specific, what I'm trying to do is to show an spinner and block the page while the request is still coming.

I tried with an interceptor but in my opinion is getting much too complicated. I would like to create a component smart enough to manage it internally. I was thinking to pass that component the Observable itself? I have to investigate more.

Comment: use Http Interceptors. you can read more about it https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: Uh, I do it the exact same way usually. Why is this ugly? If you have a generic component (like an overlay over the complete page), yes, you might pass the observable. But usually, the loading indicator behaves differently on different components (e.g. a loading spinner while data is loaded and the button disabled while data is saved).

Answer (score 0):

Using a flag like you did is a really solid practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the observable and then tap it with a pipe https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/operators/utility/do.md .

Something like that

```
registerObservable(o: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return o.pipe(tap(() => this.isEnded = true))
}
```

You need to subscribe to the returned observable and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution for every single HTTP request, use an interceptor:
https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

For an attachment as you used in your example (a request with longer response times), you might want to show progres... Then use:
https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events